# WPF Binding ADO.Net Entity Framework to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, binding, combobox

I am working on a small system for a summer camp in WPF. I have a database that is linked via ADO.Net Entity Framework. It contains two tables; Campers & Bunks. The structure is as follows:

**Campers**

- CustomerID, INT (Key)
- Name, NVARCHAR
- BunkID, INT

**Bunks**

- BunkID, INT (Key)
- Name, NVARCHAR

There is a foreign key relationship to for the link between Campers.BunkID & Bunks.BunkID

I made a WPF Window that consists of a **ListBox** of all the customers and a **UserControl** that displays the details of the customer selected in the **ListBox** . The **UserControl** consists of a **TextBlock** for the *CamperID* , **TextBox** for the *Name* of the camper and **ComboBox** for the *Bunk* of the camper.

Now the hard part... I have two questions:

1. What is the best method to bind the list of all the *Campers* to the **ListBox** ? What is the best way to bind the list of all the *Bunks* to the **ComboBox** in the **UserControl** ?
2. I cannot figure out how to bind the **ComboBox** correctly such that it displays the *Bunk* for each *Camper* and can be updated by changing the value.

Currently I am doing both in the code behind in C# but with the strength of WPF, I can't imagine that a simpler and better solution does not exist...

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Did you spend some time with learning the basics of Binding and Templating? Then you should be able to solve your problems. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You should do 3 things:

1. Set the ListBox's ItemSource property to the Campers object (I assume this is an IEnumerable of some kind..)
2. Set the DisplayMemeberPath property to the actual property you want to display on the ListBox (for instance - "CustomerFirstName"). If you want it to be a bit more complex you can create your own DataTemplate and present whatever you want (more than one property, images, etc)
3. Bind the UserControl to the ListBox's selected item: